# Do "without being disturbed" and "as being undisturbed" have similar meanings?

Tags: meaning, prepositions, gerunds

In one school's mid-term English exam, there was a question that had three blanks to fill in.

> When you sleep, it is important to get a good night's sleep  _______ _______ _________
>   by 'sleep thieves'such as night lights, TV, computer, or cell phone.

Original[intended] answer is **without being disturbed**

Would **‘as being undisturbed’** also work?

I think it a little awkward, but possible.

Thank you for your kind opinions in advance.

Comment: I'd say no... the "as" just doesn't work.  Replacing it with a comma would work, but would only fill 2 blanks.  "And be undisturbed" would fit and wouldn't sound bad to my US ears, though.  Just my kind opinion without references, hence the comment.

Comment: No, it would not work.

Answer (score 1):

In the intended answer, "without" is a [preposition](https://www.google.com/#q=define:preposition), and its phrase ("without being disturbed...") differentiates the kind of sleep being discussed as uninterrupted sleep (as opposed to interrupted sleep), performing the function of an adjective on the noun "sleep".

> When you sleep, it is important to get a good night's sleep without being disturbed by *sleep thieves*, such as night lights, TVs, computers, and cell phones.

In the other answer ("as being undisturbed"), "as" is a [conjunction](https://www.google.com/#q=define:conjunction), but the sentence is not a compound sentence, as it lacks two distinct, separable thoughts. Adding such a thought yields:

> When you sleep, it is important to get a good night's sleep, as being undisturbed by *sleep thieves* (such as night lights, TVs, computers, and cell phones) will help you avoid the symptoms of sleep deprivation.

In this alteration, the construction is: [Sentence 1], [conjunction] [sentence 2]. Here they are as separate sentences:

> When you sleep, it is important to get a good night's sleep. Being undisturbed by *sleep thieves* (such as night lights, TVs, computers, and cell phones) will help you avoid the symptoms of sleep deprivation.

Comment: to lirmont, But it's not 'as being disturbed' but ' as being undisturbed,

Comment: @user235182 The positive or negative nature of that word (disturbed/undisturbed) does not change the part of speech of "as" from a conjunction to something else, just the meaning of the second thought (which does not exist in the exam question).

Comment: If the sentence "When you sleep, it is important to get a good night's sleep while(as) you are not disturbed by 'sleep thieves'such as night lights, TV, computer, or cell phone."  instead of 'without being disturbed', would 'as being undisturbed' or 'while being undisturbed' also work?

Comment: @user235182 The "while" in the following sentence is an adverb (answering "when" to get sleep) and is a valid replacement: When you sleep, it is important to get a good night's sleep while being undisturbed by "sleep thieves". There is some redundancy there, and it would more likely be rendered as: It is important to sleep while being undisturbed by "sleep thieves".